# I know the object value, How can I return just the object property?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing this [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/kata/54da5a58ea159efa38000836/train/javascript)
I want return the object property is possible do it when I know the object value ?

```
function findOdd(A) {
    
        let counter = {};
        let finalResult;

   const NumInt =  A.sort((a, b)=> a - b)

    NumInt.forEach((e)=>{counter[e] = (counter[e] || 0) +1})
    console.log(counter)

    const values = Object.values(counter).filter((value)=>{
        return value % 2 !== 0
    })

    Object.values(counter).filter((value)=>{
       if(value % 2 !== 0){
           return console.log(value)
       }
    })
  }

  findOdd([1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5])
```

Comment: Could you kindly clarify your question? Which object you're talking about? You can get the keys or property names of an object by using `Object.keys(your-object)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Object.values()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values so it's not what you want in your case.

You can iterate through the `for...in` statement which iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings to achieve that.

```js
function findOdd(A) {
    
        let counter = {};
        let finalResult;

   const NumInt =  A.sort((a, b)=> a - b)

    NumInt.forEach((e)=>{counter[e] = (counter[e] || 0) +1})
    console.log(counter)

    const values = Object.values(counter).filter((value)=>{
        return value % 2 !== 0
    })

    for (const el in counter){
       if(counter[el] % 2 !== 0){
           return console.log(el, counter[el]); //logs property name and it's value
       }
    }
  }

  findOdd([1,1,2,-2,5,2,4,4,-1,-2,5])
```

Comment: thank you so much :D

Comment: @Guilhax - you're weIcome. I would appreciate if you accept the answer and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't loop an object using array built-in functions like map, forEach, for...of

I'm posting one solution here.

```
const data = {
   2: 0,
   1: 2,
   3: 1,
   4: 7,
   5: 9
}

for (const key in data) {
    if (data[key] % 2 === 1)
        console.log(key, data[key])
}
```

Other possible ways are using
`Object.keys()` and `Object.values()`

Or
`Object.entries()`

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object storing the *key,occurrences* couples and then filter the only one key with an odd occurrence with [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?retiredLocale=it) and [`Object#keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?retiredLocale=it):

```js
function findOdd(arr) {
  const occurrences = arr.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
    acc[curr] = acc[curr] ? acc[curr] + 1 : 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  const result = Object.keys(occurrences).find(key => (occurrences[key] % 2) === 1);
  
  return Number(result);
}

console.log(findOdd([7]) === 7);
console.log(findOdd([0]) === 0);
console.log(findOdd([1, 1, 2]) === 2);
console.log(findOdd([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]) === 0);
console.log(findOdd([1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1]) === 4);
```